# ¿Como agrupar una columna con rowspan PHP?

Tags: php, html

Necesito hacer un rowspan dentro de un for

Tengo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el resultado que deseo obtener es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intenado con esto pero no me funciona

```
<table id="tablaCS" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Org Account</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <?php

    for ($i=0; $i < count($listadoMT_SMS_DATA["ORG_ACCOUNT"]) ; $i++) 
    { 
        if($listadoMT_SMS_DATA["ORG_ACCOUNT"][$i] == 'OtaDMC' or $listadoMT_SMS_DATA["ORG_ACCOUNT"][$i] == 'otarca1')
        {
            echo "<tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>".$listadoMT_SMS_DATA["ORG_ACCOUNT"][$i]."</td>
            <td><strong>".$listadoMT_SMS_DATA["TOTAL_MT"][$i]."</strong></td>
            </tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas meter una condición en el `echo` dentro del `for` para meter el `rowspan`.

```
<table id="tablaCS" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Org Account</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <?php

    for ($i=0; $i < count($listadoMT_SMS_DATA["ORG_ACCOUNT"]) ; $i++) 
    { 
        if($listadoMT_SMS_DATA["ORG_ACCOUNT"][$i] == 'OtaDMC' or $listadoMT_SMS_DATA["ORG_ACCOUNT"][$i] == 'otarca1')
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            if($i==0) echo "<td rowspan=2></td>";                
            echo "<td>".$listadoMT_SMS_DATA["ORG_ACCOUNT"][$i]."</td>
            <td><strong>".$listadoMT_SMS_DATA["TOTAL_MT"][$i]."</strong></td>
            </tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</tr>
```

Te he puesto como ejemplo el `rowspan=2` por el ejemplo que has dado y la condición `$i=0` porque para este ejemplo vale.

Pero si necesitas agruparlos de alguna manera tendrás que buscar una condición que se adecue y añadir el `rowspan` que quieras.

Comment: Me sale este error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Comment: Tenía un punto en vez de punto y como, culpa mía.

Comment: Consulta en el valor $i==0 no trae el campo OtaDMC, otarca1 sino en el 5 pero puede variar porque va dependiendo de la cantidad que esten en la BD me explico ?

Comment: Gateway_G 35
smsgw  28
VMSTRWI  25
sdp   23
ocs   21
OtaDMC  19
PcRf  19
WSMS  18
otarca1  15
MNP_icon 3
wapgw  2

Comment: Si te fijas en este no lo trae en la misma posicion 

Gateway_G 37
smsgw  34
VMSTRWI  29
sdp   28
otarca1  23
WSMS  22
ocs   20
OtaDMC  18
PcRf  13
MNP_icon 4

Comment: Pues tendrás que añadir más condifciones y controlar, las posibles variaciones que puedas tener.

Comment: Es que es dinamico eso, porque viene de la BD puede que el registro pro ejemplo de WSMS no traiga nada